# /usr/bin/ld cannot find headers: File format not recognized

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

When attempting to compile a program I get the following output:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find headers/dir1: File format not recognized
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find headers/dir1/dir11: File format not recognized
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find headers/dir1/dir12: File format not recognized
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find headers/dir1/dir13: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The project is comprised of .c and .cpp sources as well as a main.cpp (LOCAL_SRC_FILES).
The directories and subdirectories dir*/dir* (LOCAL_C_INCLUDES) contain .h header files.

The command I use to compile is:

```
gcc $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES) -I $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)
```

I have seen this issue discussed a number of times but it generally relates to libraries not being recognized rather than header files.

Do you have any suggestions as to why this might be occurring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expand your variables on the command line you would get something like:

```
gcc file1.cpp file2.cpp -I headers/dir1 headers/dir2
```

As headers/dir2 isn't prefixed with "-I" gcc treats it as a source file. The command needs to be:

```
gcc file1.cpp file2.cpp -I headers/dir1 -I headers/dir2
```